# Blazor wasm: cascading RouteData from top component to inner component fires ParameterSet twice

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Last week, amd even though I'm no Blazor expert, I was called to help with a Blazor Wasm app that was firing the `SetParametersAsync` method twice when the app navigates to an URI that has at least one querystring parameter (if there's at least one, then it will end up firing the `ParametersSetAsync`method twice).

First, let me give some more info about the app and why this behavior is problematic. In order to support resource uri sharing, most actions generates an uri to which the app navigates to. In practice, this means that most actions end up navigating to an uri, which is handled by a page that has several parameters that are fed from the querystring parameters present on the URI.

For instance, suppose you have a page (`/demo`) that shows a list of items which can be filtered by a couple of fields (lets say `A`, `B`, `C`). Whenever a user clicks the filter button, a new URI is generated (`/demo?A=...&B=...&C=...`) and its passed the `NavigationManager,NavigateTo`. This ends up calling the `SetParametersAsync` method which is responsible for getting the information and showing it to the user (in this case, it will call several web services in order to get the required data).

After some testing, I've noticed that the problematic pages (ie, those where the `SetParametersAsync` method is called twice) are getting an instance of the `RouteData` object through a `CascadeParameter` which is being passed from the top component.

In order to reproduce the behavior, you just need to create a new Blazor WebAssemly App and change the default generated code to the following:

```
@*App.razor*@

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof( App ).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="@routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof( MainLayout )"/>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    ...
</Router>
```

```
@*Index.razor*@

@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?"/>
<Button @onclick="Navigate">Click me</Button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public RouteData? RouteData { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "in")]
    [Parameter]
    public string Info { get; set; }

    private void Navigate() {
        var uri = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameter("in", DateTime.Now.ToString( ));
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
    }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters) {
        await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine($"Navigation: {Info}");
    }
}
```

If you run the previous sample, you'll notice that cascading the `RouteData` tends to mess things up and that the method will be called with the date that was passed through the uri and then with an empty date (I'm accessing the property, not the querystring value directly). If there's no `RouteData` parameter being cascaded, then everything runs just fine.

I've tried searching the docs but haven't found anything which says that cascading shouldn't be used with `RouteData` parameters. Granted: I'm not a Blazor wizard and I haven't needed to cascade the `RouteData` in my apps (and in this case, it probably wasn't required either), but I'd really love that someone could confirm this behavior and, if possible, point me to some official document from MS that justifies this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetParamnetersAsync` isn't being called twice, the component is being rendered twice.  Subtle different.

This will take a little explaining, but to show that it's nothing to do with routes here's my demo `App` that does the same thing:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="@value">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    public string value => $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
}
```

Here's my Index with aome extra logging:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<div class="m2 p-2">
    <Button @onclick="Navigate">Click me</Button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    <pre>@_log.ToString()</pre>
</div>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter] public string? Data { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "in")]
    [Parameter] public string Info { get; set; }

    private System.Text.StringBuilder _log = new();

    private void Navigate()
    {
        var uri = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameter("in", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
    }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        var message = $"Render at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        _log.AppendLine(message);
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
        var navMessage = $"Navigation: {Info}";
        _log.AppendLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} : {navMessage}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} : {navMessage}");
    }
}
```

Here's the log with the key element highlighted.  Note the Render time verses the Navigation time.  The render occured with the old data?

[image]

The reason is that when the `Route` component renders, the renderer knows that `Index` has a reference to the cascade and the cascaded value has changed.  It therefore calls `SetParametersAsync` on `Index` which renders the component.  It then renders `RouteView` which renders `Index` (again), this time with the new data.

It's one of the side effects of cascading objects, and `ComponentBase`'s render logic.  The render doesn't know if an object has changed, so everytime it renders the owning component, all the cascade capturing components also get rendered.  If you look through the Microsoft code base you will see that most cascades are set to `IsFixed`.

In this instance I would probably use an event driven model rather than the cascade.  I've provided an example below.

The provider and `EventArgs`.

```cs
public class RouteDataProvider
{
    public event EventHandler<RouteDataEventArgs>? RouteChangd;

    public RouteData? RouteData { get; private set; }

    public void NotifyRouteChanged(RouteData routeData)
    {
        this.RouteData = routeData;
        this.RouteChangd?.Invoke(this, new(routeData));
    }
}

public class RouteDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
    public RouteDataEventArgs(RouteData routeData)
        => this.RouteData = routeData;
}
```

Updated `App` with a fixed cascade.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value=_routeDataProvider IsFixed>
            @{
                _routeDataProvider.NotifyRouteChanged(routeData);
            }
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    private readonly RouteDataProvider _routeDataProvider = new();
}
```

And `Index`:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<div class="m2 p-2">
    <Button @onclick="Navigate">Click me</Button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    <pre>@_log.ToString()</pre>
</div>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter] public RouteDataProvider? _routeDataProvider { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "in")]
    [Parameter] public string Info { get; set; }

    private System.Text.StringBuilder _log = new();

    private void Navigate()
    {
        var uri = NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameter("in", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
    }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        var message = $"Render at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        _log.AppendLine(message);
        _log.AppendLine($"Route Component: {_routeDataProvider?.RouteData?.PageType.FullName ?? "Not defined"}");
        Console.WriteLine(message);

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
        var navMessage = $"Navigation: {Info}";
        _log.AppendLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} : {navMessage}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} : {navMessage}");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, this will happen whenever we have routing with parameter cascading and not only when we cascade routedata?

Comment: Yes.  I've added the code for an alternative cleaner approach to cascading objects.

Comment: Hello again. I've updated my sample locally so that it cascades a regular string property (instead of the routeData property), but when I do this, I'm not seeing duplicate calls (ie, the parametersetasync method is called only once in that case). cascading the routedata does produce the duplicate calls though...I believe I might be missing something and I'm thinking that cascading routedata (like I've done) is not really a good idea...

Comment: A string is a value type, so if the string doesn't change the cascade isn't updated.  In my example the string is updated every time and there causes the cascade.  See my add on to the answer for better way to do it.